# Character Creator 3 to Blender - Reimporting a texture that was accidentally deleted

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I still have an original CC3 export and I want to avoid starting again as much as possible because I've already done sculpting on the mesh and vertex groups for a dozen hair particles. (wish i was joking)

Is there a video that would help guide me to reimporting the texture i need properly? (std_skin_head) I can bring the texture back in but it's not aligned to the mesh anymore. Before you ask - yes the texture was working fine after i sculpted the mesh.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fsM5IuFQbI Videos like this that describe material setup are not relevant, they do not cover the application of a base texture.

If you don't know about character creator 3 but you want to help, I'll briefly explain what it does. It's a third party program that you can quickly create a character model in - when it exports it creates armature and textures and maps out all the textures along with the mesh. So /somewhere/ **there is something already made that can guide this texture onto my mesh** but I don't know where it is or how to apply it.

Comment: Hi. [Requests for tutorials are considered off topic here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1). If it requires a full tutorial the question is either [too broad and needs to be narrowed down](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62) to a more specific issue; or it can be solved with a simple web search, which you can easily do yourself. Please don't post another question. If you could you rephrase the current one to read more like a direct inquiry about your issue, rather than pointing you to a link, you can [edit] it so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

CC3's vertex groups can be set to textures. Linking related videos for future CC3 users.

https://www.google.com/search?q=assign+vertex+group+to+texture+blender&rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBAU900AU900&oq=assign+vertex+group+to+texture+blender&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i22i29i30.8902j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_hKRrYOfpHuObmgf7g5v4BQ17

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTd8NBg8EZU